# Macro give Error 91 second time when other macro runs and closes an userform

Tags: vba, excel, object

I have two macros. One macro is used for re-sizing the excel sheet for different monitors by minimizing ribbons and zoom in feature. Another macro where i can write some problems in a particular excel sheet table using the text input from the user. This macro activates a userform where the user can enter the data.
1st macro runs perfectly in all the excel sheet as expected. If i run second macro one time and tried to run the 1st macro  again. It always give object variable not set error on 1st macro in the line ***" MaxCol  = Rows(1)....".*** I have to close and reopen it in order to run the 1st macro again.

I have no idea why this is arising. I have properly closed (Unloaded) the object of Userform if user presses ok or cancel.

Below is the code for first macro.

```
Sub OptimalSize()

Dim SheetName As String
Dim MaxCol As Long

SheetName = ""
MaxCol = 0

CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"

Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

MaxCol = Rows(1).Find(1, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

Sheets(SheetName).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(1, MaxCol)).Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A1"), Scroll:=True  
End Sub
```

The second macro after some computation which calls the userform

```
Sub ProblemBoard()

' code here to find out empty space in a table!!'

 Userform1.Show 
End sub
```

The userform code below

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Problem Board").Cells(z, 2).Value = TextBox1.Text
Worksheets("Problem Board").Cells(z, 5).Value = TextBox2.Text

Unload Me
Sheets(ActWS).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  Unload Me
  Sheets(ActWS).Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim lng As Long

'ActWS = ActiveSheet.Name

lng  = Sheets("Listen").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Me.ComboBox2.List = Sheets("Listen").Range("A2:A" & lng ).Value
TextBox1 = ""
TextBox2 = ""

End Sub
```